# Is there a good Guitar Chord building web site?

Tags: guitar, chords

I'm looking for a chord builder web site. Is there one that shows what strings are being played and what chord it is?
I'm specifically looking for the following chord, but ask for a web site so I can learn to fish.

```
$6.x.$5.0.$4.2.$3.1.$2.2.$1.0 ||
```

Comment: This is Amaj7 chord.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Feel free to add websites/apps/etc to the list below.

List of Guitar Chord Websites

- [Chord Find](http://chordfind.com/)
- [Chorderator](http://www.chorderator.com/)
- [Study Bass](http://www.studybass.com/tools/chord-scale-note-printer/)
- [Chord Book](http://www.chordbook.com/guitarchords.php)
- [Gitarrengriffe Online (German)](http://gitarrengriffe-online.de/)

List of Guitar Chord Apps

- [Guitar Toolkit](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/guitartoolkit/id284962368?mt=8)
- [Garage Band Chord Trainer](http://www.apple.com/ilife/garageband/#basic-lessons)

Answer (score 5):

This site is gona do it for You:

http://chordfind.com/

Here You can browse by chord type and see chord shape on fretboard, or enter the fret numebers or x - and find a chord name.

This is a basic to intermediate chord site, You won't find any advanced voicings there.

Answer (score 5):

Chorderator lets you look up chord shapes by name, names by shape, and scales, in any tuning.

http://www.chorderator.com

Comment: That is a great designed web site!!

Answer (score 1):

I use this one:

http://www.studybass.com/tools/chord-scale-note-printer/

Don't let the url fool you, this little tool can give you chords and scales for most stringed instrument.

Very handy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone app Guitar Toolkit is awesome for this type of chord search. You can plot the exact fingering and it will tell you what chord you have. This differs from most chord lookup sites and apps in that you don't have to search through a bunch of chords to identify the one you are looking for.

Find it here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/guitartoolkit/id284962368?mt=8

There may be some other resources out there to look up chords in this "reverse engineering" approach, but this app is something I started using when it first came out and is a good all in one tool for a number of things.

Comment: There's also an app called Guitar Tools, by Planet Waves, which is great as it has both types of chord lookup. You can name the chord and scroll through different voicings, OR you can punch in your fingerings and it'll tell you the chord. (It also has a scale tool, tuner and metronome). My only complaint is that I can never remember which type of chord lookup tool I need; they're rather cryptically named. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/planet-waves-guitar-tools/id375703586?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/top/top100.htm and
http://www.hotfrets.com/chordfinder.asp are the best guitar website, I know so far.

pretty cool!
Hope will help you!

Answer (score -2):

This is a good one I've been using though:
http://musictheorysite.com/namethatchord